# wp_schedule_event is executing but the function related to the hook is not running

Tags: wp-cron

I have an OOP plugin, The purpose of the plugin is to catch scheduled posts, save them in cron, then 2 minutes after they are published, to run a custom function on them.

This is the stripped-down class with the relevant parts to the question:

```
class fb_linter {

    function __construct() {

        add_action('init', array($this,'init') );
        add_action('admin_init', array($this,'admin_init') );
        add_action('admin_menu', array($this,'admin_menu') );

        add_action( 'future_post',  array(&$this, 'on_post_scheduled'), 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'activate_cron', array(&$this,'post_notification'), 10, 1);

        }

    function on_post_scheduled( $ID, $post ) {
        $title = $post->post_title;
        if ($post->post_status == 'future') {
            wp_schedule_single_event(get_post_time('U', true , $post->ID) + 120, 'activate_cron', array($post->ID));
        }
    }

    function post_notification($post_id) {
        $title = get_the_title($post_id);
        $permalink = get_permalink($post_id);
        $headers = 'From: My Name <myname@example.com>' . "\r\n";
        wp_mail('wp@gmail.com', 'Post ' . $title', $headers);
    }
}
```

I'm able to get the action in the cron, means I can see activate_cron inside Crontrol & Crony menus, but the function **post_notification** never executing.

When I transfer the **add_action** call of **activate_cron** and the function **post_notifications** to *functions.php*, everything works correctly.

I kept digging for the last 3 days for a solution, but I couldn't get it to work.

Any advices?

Comment: Were you able to get this figured out? I seem to be running into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

So your constructor is probably not being executed before the cron event is being run. If your instantiating the fb_linter class too late then your call to `add_action` won't happen in time. Try using the singleton design pattern for your class and then instantiate it right after you declare it and it should work just fine.

something like

```
class fb_linter {
    public static function get_instance(){
        static $instance;
        if( ! isset( $instance ) )
            $instance = new self();

        return $instance;
    }

    ...
}
fb_linter::get_instance();
```